# Show group header once while exporting a Jasper report to Excel

Tags: jasper-reports

I’m working on a Jasper report, and can’t get the group header to be shown once when the report is exported to excel.

According to the documentation (if I get it right), this should work:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.2" value="groupHeader">
```

I’ve also tried some options with more filters like this:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.2" value="groupHeader">

<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.group.2" value="MyGroup">

<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.2" value="*">
```

But none of that works. However when I export this report to PDF the group header is visible.

Maybe something is wring with the JRXML file structure?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="1040" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9d48e8d2-39a9-4d94-a4eb-d5ee2a2f2cf2">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.field.delimiter" value=";"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.3" value="title"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.4" value="summary"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.2" value="groupHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span" value="true"/>
    
    <group name="MyGroup" keepTogether="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{someDataType}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="70">
            
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="30" width="90" height="40" backcolor="#CCFFCC" uuid="d398729c-74c6-4c80-b13a-26d2678f7cb3"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="12" isItalic="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Header1]]></text>
                </staticText>
                
                <staticText>
                    ...
                </staticText>                               
                                            
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="360" y="0" width="250" height="20" uuid="37c73a23-38ba-4cb8-856e-ef8013fd3d99"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="13" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{someDataType}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    
    <title>
        <band height="57" splitType="Stretch">
            ...
        </band>
    </title>
    
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
        
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="-4" width="90" height="30" uuid="2dfc7adf-5014-4caa-8c35-2e79339698a8"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{someData}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                ...
            </textField>
                        
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```